# Spring MVC Initialization Causes Log4J Exception

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j, weblogic

In my webapp, I am using Spring MVC as my controller layer. However, using the tags provided by the MVC context:

```
<mvn:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources />
```

causes a log4j exception:

```
<Mar 26, 2012 1:49:50 PM EDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener         
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/ThrowableInformation.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/ThrowableInformation
at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:165)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:597)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.error(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:225)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

> (LoggingEvent.java:165)
>       at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
>       at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
>       at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:597)
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.error(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:225)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Basic stuff:

1. log4j-1.2.16.jar is defined in the maven POM and is in the application library.
2. Since it's a weblogic server, I have the following in the weblogic.xml file to try to prevent conflicts:

   ```
   <wls:prefer-application-packages>
       <wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name>
   </wls:prefer-application-packages>
   ```
3. (Update) I manually excluded commons-logging in the maven POM for the application.
4. (Update) I already had the slf4j jars in my Maven POM (removing the jcl-over-slf4j has no effect):

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.8</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.8</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.8</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

Basically, I need to exclude the basic css and js directories as web as a single directory under WEB-INF/ that contains some jspf files that I do NOT wish to write a controller for (dropdown menus definitions used by jquery superfish).

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add slf4j-log4 connector to the POM:

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Already had it in there. I updated the original question to clarify that I already had that.

Comment: try to change log4j version to 1.2.8

Comment: Check that you only 
have one version of Log4j in your classpath

Comment: also, try to remove log4j jar from the classpath

Comment: Changing the version seems to have worked. Looking at the original source, there was apparently a conflict with one of the constructors inlog4j's  ThrowableInformation class.